# K3s kubeconfig authenticate with token instead of client cert

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I set up K3s on a server with:

```
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | K3S_TOKEN={token} INSTALL_K3S_EXEC="server --cluster-init --disable=traefik --write-kubeconfig-mode 644" sh -s -
```

Then I grabbed the kube config from `/etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml` and copy it to my local machine so I can interact with the cluster from my machine rather than the server node I installed K3s on. I had to swap out references to 127.0.0.1 and change it to the actual hostname of the server I installed K3s on as well but other than that it worked.

I then hooked up 2 more server nodes to the cluster for a High Availability setup using:

```
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | K3S_TOKEN={token} INSTALL_K3S_EXEC="server --server {https://{hostname or IP of server 1}:6443 --disable=traefik --write-kubeconfig-mode 644" sh -s -
```

Now on my local machine again I run `kubectl get pods` (for example) and that works but I want a highly available setup so I placed a TCP Load Balancer (NGINX actually) in front of my cluster. Now I am trying to connect to the Kubernetes API through that proxy / load balancer and unfortunately, since my `~/.kube/config` has a client certificate for authentication, this no longer works because my load balancer / proxy that lives in front of that server cannot pass my client cert on to the K3s server.

My `~/.kube/config`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: {omitted}
    server: https://my-cluster-hostname:6443
  name: default
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: default
    user: default
  name: default
current-context: default
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: default
  user:
    client-certificate-data: {omitted}
    client-key-data: {omitted}
```

I also grabbed that client cert and key in my kube config, exported it to a file, and hit the API server with curl and it works when I directly hit the server nodes but NOT when I go through my proxy / load balancer.

What I would like to do instead of using the client certificate approach is use `token` authentication as my proxy would not interfere with that. However, I am not sure how to get such a token. I read the [Kubernetes Authenticating guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/) and specifically I tried creating a new service account and getting the token associated with it as described in the [Service Account Tokens](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#service-account-tokens) section but that also did not work. I also dug through [K3s server config options](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/install-options/server-config/) to see if there was any mention of static token file, etc. but didn't find anything that seemed likely.

Is this some limitation of K3s or am I just doing something wrong (likely)?

My `kubectl version` output:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.7", GitCommit:"132a687512d7fb058d0f5890f07d4121b3f0a2e2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-05-12T12:40:09Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.12", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.7+k3s1", GitCommit:"ac70570999c566ac3507d2cc17369bb0629c1cc0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-11-29T16:40:13Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Added my `kubectl version` output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out an approach that works for me by reading through the [Kubernetes Authenticating Guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/) in more detail. I settled on the [Service Account Tokens](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#service-account-tokens) approach as it says:

> Normally these secrets are mounted into pods for in-cluster access to
> the API server, but can be used from outside the cluster as well.

My use is for outside the cluster.

First, I created a new `ServiceAccount` called `cluster-admin`:

```
kubectl create serviceaccount cluster-admin
```

I then created a `ClusterRoleBinding` to assign cluster-wide permissions to my ServiceAccount (I named this `cluster-admin-manual` because K3s already had created one called `cluster-admin` that I didn't want to mess with):

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-manual --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=default:cluster-admin
```

Now you have to get the `Secret` that is created for you when you created your `ServiceAccount`:

```
kubectl get serviceaccount cluster-admin -o yaml
```

You'll see something like this returned:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-12-20T15:55:55Z"
  name: cluster-admin
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "3973955"
  uid: 66bab124-8d71-4e5f-9886-0bad0ebd30b2
secrets:
- name: cluster-admin-token-67jtw
```

Get the Secret content with:

```
kubectl get secret cluster-admin-token-67jtw -o yaml
```

In that output you will see the `data/token` property. This is a base64 encoded JWT bearer token. Decode it with:

```
echo {base64-encoded-token} | base64 --decode
```

Now you have your bearer token and you can add a user to your `~/.kube/config` with the following command. You can also paste that JWT into [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) to take a look at the properties and make sure you base64 decoded it properly.

```
kubectl config set-credentials my-cluster-admin --token={token}
```

Then make sure your existing `context` in your `~/.kube/config` has the user set appropriately (I did this manually by editing my kube config file but there's probably a `kubectl config` command for it). For example:

```yaml
- context:
    cluster: my-cluster
    user: my-cluster-admin
  name: my-cluster
```

My user in the kube config looks like this:

```yaml
- name: my-cluster-admin
  user:
    token: {token}
```

Now I can authenticate to the cluster using the token instead of relying on a transport layer specific mechanism (TLS with Mutual Auth) that my proxy / load-balancer does not interfere with.

Other resources I found helpful:

- [Kubernetes — Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) Overview by Anish Patel](https://medium.com/devops-mojo/kubernetes-role-based-access-control-rbac-overview-introduction-rbac-with-kubernetes-what-is-2004d13195df)